# Item disappears when array is sorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I recently learned how to sort an array of integers into ascending order. I am trying to program a game and part of it involved creating a layered texture renderer; however, when two objects are exactly the same level (the y positions are the same) one of them disappears due to the sorting process.

Why is this? Here is my code:

```
public void sort() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < yposCount) {
        order[i] = ypos[i];
        i++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(order);
    int j = 0;
    while (j < yposCount) {
        int k = 0;
        while (k < yposCount) {
            if (order[j] == ypos[k]) {
                finalOrder[j] = k;
            }
            k++;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The algorithms of sorting is very good documented, what language what data structure you use?

Comment: Better you edit this code in your question. Its unreadable here.

Comment: I really think that you need to explain more on what is happening here. This is so convoluted that it actually *smells* bad...

Comment: Well, to start with I had some textures for characters in my game engine and was drawing them on screen. However, the one I drew first always appeared behind the one I drew second even if it should be the other way around! I then wrote that bit of code up there to arrange them in the correct order based on the y position of the bottom right hand corner. Now though, when two things are exactly the same level one of them is not drawn at all. This is something to do with the sort. I no understand!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(order);
int j = 0;
while (j < yposCount) {
    int k = 0;
    while (k < yposCount) {
        if (order[j] == ypos[k]) {
            finalOrder[j] = k;
        }
        k++;
    }
    j++;
}
```

For each `ypos` value, since you don't `break;` after you found a match, you always write every index `k` that matches to the `finalOrder` array at index `j`. Thus only the last matching index remains recorded.

If for a given `ypos` value `v` there are `m` indices with `ypos[k] == v`, you write the largest of these indices `m` times to `finalOrder` and the remaining `m-1` indices are always overwritten. Thus the corresponding objects are not recorded in `finalOrder`.

To fix that, increment the `j` index when you find a match and the next element of `order` equals the current.

```
Arrays.sort(order);
int j = 0;
while (j < yposCount) {
    int k = 0;
    while (k < yposCount) {
        if (order[j] == ypos[k]) {
            finalOrder[j] = k;
            // Now, if the next `order` is equal, continue looking for that value
            if ((j+1 < yposCount) && (order[j+1] == order[j])) {
                // more of the same ypos values to come
                j++;
            } else {
                // All these ypos values found, end inner loop
                break;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    j++;
}
```

Comment: This works for a split second and then the character disappears again, thanks for trying though

Comment: Ah, duh. My brain inserted a `break;` in the inner loop when the matching `ypos` is found. You don't have one.

Comment: Now the other object has gone invisible, it used to be the one drawn first, now it is the one drawn second

???

Comment: @Dr_N See the update, now every index appears exactly once in `finalOrder`. That should ensure that everybody is drawn.